# Code first - connecting to my database ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created a ASP.NET 5 project with Identity.
And I wanted to try code first, which I have not done before.

So in my `Models` folder, I created a new folder called `Database`, where I can keep all my database related models. (Not sure if this is the standard).

I then created this small `character model` for testing purposes.

```
namespace IdleV4.Models.Database
{
    public class Character
    {
        public Character()
        {

        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I created a `context` class

```
namespace IdleV4.Models.Database
{
    public class DatabaseContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext(): base()
        {

        }

        public DbSet <Character> Characters { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then in `appsettings.json` I found the connection string, which seems to work fine and adds Identity users.
But I want it to connect to my database, which I have been searching a lot about, but can't figure out.

This is the connection string in `appsettings.json`, which I don't know how to change, and implement in my code in order to use my database.

```
"Data": {
"DefaultConnection": {
  "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet5-IdleV4-39fb8cfe-f209-4577-9039-f64ce1551c3d;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

This is what my connection strings in my old project looks like, and it's the database I want to connect to.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IdentityString" connectionString="Data Source=secret.database.windows.net; Initial Catalog=secret; User ID=secret; Password=secret; Connect Timeout=60;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DatabaseContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Database.csdl|res://*/Models.Database.ssdl|res://*/Models.Database.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=secret.database.windows.net;initial catalog=secret;persist security info=True;user id=secret;password=secret;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

How can I go from this old connection string, where I used an `edmx` model, to a code first ASP.NET 5 connection string?

Thank you.